# console.log does not work as expected in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying learn jQuery, and there is a problem in my code.
There is a select html tag and when the user alters her change, it does something.

The source code below a tool to selects the user some mp3 files.

I have given the correspondent javascript action codes of the *select* element

As pointed out in the comment section of the code, ***console.log(' isGreaterThanZero :' + isGreaterThanZero);*** runs properly, whereas ***console.log(' isGreaterThanZero :' + selectedIndex > 0);*** does not. If this code is written in Java, it would be run. Does it related with the fact that jquery is a interpreted language?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#slct01").change(function() {

    console.log("on change")

    var selectedIndex = $("#slct01").prop("selectedIndex");

    console.log(' selectedIndex ' + selectedIndex);
    var isGreaterThanZero = selectedIndex > 0;

    // the line is printed properly to the console.
    console.log(' isGreaterThanZero :' + isGreaterThanZero);
    // the line is not printed to the console.                      
    //console.log(' isGreaterThanZero :' + selectedIndex > 0);

    console.log(' selected value :' + $("#slct01").val());

    if (selectedIndex > 0) {

      console.log('inside if')
      $("#audio1").attr("src", "media/" + $("#slct01").val());
      $("#audio1").get(0).play();
    }

  });

  // other codes omitted for brevity

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- page 144 -->
<h1>DropDownList change Event Handler</h1>

<form>

  <label id="lblCounter" class="normalSayac"> </label> <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="Button1" onClick="return submit();" />

  <select name="slct01" id="slct01">
    <option value="1">Please Select</option>
    <option value="Audio1.mp3">Audio1.mp3</option>
    <option value="Audio2.mp3">Audio2.mp3</option>
    <option value="Audio3.mp3">Audio3.mp3</option>
  </select> <input type="checkbox" id="chkboxShowControls" value="Show Controls">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkboxPlayInLoop" value="Play in loop">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkboxMute" value="Mute">

  <audio id="audio1"></audio>

</form>
```

Comment: `selectedIndex`  if set with the value of an html property it's probably a string. So if you compose the string like that with `selectedIndex > 0`, that part won't be evaluated correctly as a number. In general you can check the type of a value doing `typeof selectedIndex`. And to convert a string to number: `parseFloat(selectedIndex)` or `parseInt(selectedIndex)`. JQuery is just a Javascript library and everything runs as javascript: a loosely typed language.

Comment: Thank you for your response Diego De Vita.

Comment: What do you mean by it does not run properly? What error you are getting? or what is the behavior that you are expecting? **FYI** You can debug javascript code from console window and easily spot the issue.

Comment: By the words "does not run properly", I mean, it does not alert an error. I does nothing. For that reason, you review the console with great care in order to point the inconvenience. I expect printing something to the console. Debugging the source code from console window is expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Diego De Vita](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1221208/diego-de-vita) pointed out, selectedIndex if set with the value of an html property it's probably a string. So if you compose the string like that with selectedIndex > 0, that part won't be evaluated correctly as a number. In general you can check the type of a value doing typeof selectedIndex. And to convert a string to number: parseFloat(selectedIndex) or parseInt(selectedIndex). JQuery is just a Javascript library and everything runs as javascript: a loosely typed language. –

Answer (score 0):

Don't concatenate those two values, use a comma to separate your console log. Console log takes unlimited arguments to print on the console.

```js
var selectedIndex = 1;

console.log('isGreaterThanZero :', selectedIndex > 0)
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/prop/ prop() returns string. The trick will work but yet I would better stress that the problem was type coercion and how it behaves according to the expression.